# qmail logstash multiline filtering

Tags: logstash, grok, qmail, logstash-grok

I've been using logstash for a while now with great success for apache access logs and occasional mysql logs. I've just started to use it for qmail logs but wanted a better way to group qmail logs based on the qmail ID and be able to track bounces or other delivery failures and statuses. I've seen some stuff regarding postfix but not qmail.

Has anyone used logstash like this with qmail? How does your logstash config look? How does your Kibana dashboards look?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's an example of some qmail logs:

```
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.510987 new msg 33592
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.511087 info msg 33592: bytes 10820 from <SmallBusinessLoan.martin.cota-martin.cota=example1.com@example.com> qp 3740 uid 89
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.513616 starting delivery 1314142: msg 33592 to local example1.com-martin.cota@example1.com
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.513686 status: local 1/4 remote 1/120
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.576361 delivery 1314142: success: did_0+0+1/
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.576491 status: local 0/4 remote 1/120
Oct 15 09:26:08 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379568.576548 end msg 33592
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.579644 new msg 33603
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.579790 info msg 33603: bytes 4370 from <loansfidelity@example2.com> qp 5037 uid 89
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.582804 starting delivery 1314143: msg 33603 to local example3.com-daniel@example3.com
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.582967 status: local 1/4 remote 1/120
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.619422 delivery 1314143: success: did_0+0+1/
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.619512 status: local 0/4 remote 1/120
Oct 15 09:26:09 imappop1-mail qmail: 1413379569.619561 end msg 33603
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to track the entire anatomy of these logs. Here's my input and filter in logstash now:

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "192.168.115.61:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/messages",
        "/var/log/secure",
        "/var/log/haraka.log",
        "/var/log/maillog"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
   ]
}

input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
            add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
            add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        }
        multiline {
            pattern => "(([^\s]+)Exception.+)|(at:.+)"
            stream_identity => "%{logsource}.%{@type}"
            what => "previous"
        }
        syslog_pri { }
        date {
            match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you ask a slightly less general question and give an example of the types of logs you want to process (and how), maybe someone other than qmail users can chip in.

Comment: addded examples and config

Comment: @LoganBest Did you resolve the problem?